# Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional with dim $V>1$ and $T\in \mathscr L (V)$. Prove that $\{p(T):p\in \mathscr P(\Bbb F)\}\neq \mathscr L(V)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional with dim $V>1$ and $T\in \mathscr L (V)$.  Prove that $\{p(T):p\in \mathscr P(\Bbb F)\}\neq \mathscr L(V)$.

I believe that I can prove this if $V$ is a complex vector space, but I need assistance if $V$ is a real vector space.

My proof: Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space. Then $T$ has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some basis of $V$: $v_1,\ldots, v_n$. Since dim $V>1$, then $n>1$. Thus, span $(v_1,\ldots,v_j)$ is invariant under $p(T)$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$. Consider some $S\in \mathscr L(V)$ such that $S(v_1)=v_2$. Note that $v_1\in$ span$(v_1)$, but $v_2 \notin$ span $(v_2)$ since the basis elements are linearly independent. Then $S(v_2)\notin$ span$(v_2)$, this implies span$(v_1)$ is not invariant under S. **Thus, S is not in $\{p(T):p\in \mathscr P(\Bbb F)\}$**

If the vector space is over the real numbers *and* $T$ has and eigenvalue, then the argument above holds.

So I would like some clarification on the part I bolded, as well as some insight for if $V$ is a vector space over the reals when $T$ does not have an eigenvalue.

Comment: Hint: Start with the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, and prove that $\dim \{ p(T) : p \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{F}) \} \le \dim V$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that polynomials in $T$ commute with $T$, so if every endomorphism of $V$ was a polynomial on a single $T$, $\text{End}(V)$ would be commutative as an algebra. However, $\text{End}(V)$ is non-commutative as soon as $\dim V >1$, for it is (isomorphic to) a matrix ring. To expand, if $V$ has dimension $n>1$ over a field $\mathbb k$, then $\text{End}(V)$ is isomorphic to $M(n,\mathbb k)$, and this contains as a subalgebra $M(2,\mathbb k)$. This subalgebra is not commutative, since the following matrices do not commute:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: That still wouldn't directly help with $T$ in the center of $\operatorname{End}(V)$.  I think for this to work, you would need to do something like prove the center is $\{ \lambda \cdot \operatorname{id} : \lambda \in \mathbb{F} \}$, and then use a separate argument for those $T$.

Comment: @DanielSchelper Of course it helps! No need to do that.

Comment: Oh, wait, I think what you meant to say is that all polynomials in $T$ commute with each other, not just with $T$.  In that case the argument would make sense.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Well, that somewhat follows from $T$ commuting with polynomials in $T$. :)